# All $a \in [-2,2]$ such that $x_{2016} = a$ if $x_0 = a, x_n = x_{n-1}^2-2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I need to find all $a \in [-2,2]$ such that for the sequence defined as $x_0 = a, x_n = x_{n-1}^2-2$, $x_{2016} = a$.

$a=2$ and $a = -1$ satisfy the condition, but I need to find all values of $a$.

I know that the problem is solved using methods of trigonometry. I also suspect that one needs to use a trigonometric formula to solve for $x_n$ as a function of $n$ and $a$. But no formula like this comes to my mind. I would appreciate if anybody could give me a **hint**.

Comment: Is this from some math contest? No problem with that (unless it's an ongoing competition, and the rules forbid asking for help). We even have a tag for contest questions :-)

Comment: @No, it is from my homework on Analysis I (I am not a student, so do not get any grade, so the question does not qualify as cheating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $x=2\cos\alpha$, then
$$
x^2-2=4\cos^2\alpha-2=2\cos2\alpha.
$$

Comment: If you prefer complex exponentials, then it reads
$$(e^{i\alpha}+e^{-i\alpha})^2-2=e^{2i\alpha}+e^{-2i\alpha}.$$

Comment: I guess you new that property of $2\cos \alpha$ before, did not you? Otherwise it is unfathomable to me how one could "guess" something like this.

Comment: A trade secret @Sergey :-) This is a rescaled version of quadratic [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) $T_2(x)$. It does occur in many types of problems in this version.